# Next 5 Available Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder if anyone could tell me how I can get the next 5 available dates using a table which only stores the Weekend dates and Bank Holiday dates..  So it has to select the next 5 days which do not collide with any dates in the table.

I would like to see the following results from this list of dates:

```
07/11/2015 (Saturday)
08/11/2015 (Sunday)
09/11/2015 (Holiday)
14/11/2015 (Saturday)
15/11/2015 (Sunday)
```

Results:

```
05/11/2015 (Thursday)
06/11/2015 (Friday)
10/11/2015 (Tuesday)
11/11/2015 (Wednesday)
12/11/2015 (Thursday)`
```

Comment: What about trying something and post an issue

Comment: Not really sure where to start..

Comment: How about sample records and expected result atleast

Comment: Point Taken..  I have edited the post, probably not formatted correctly though.

Comment: The question was clear, no need for the examples you posted. You are expected to post some code and point what is the problem that you have. You cannot expect that someone will do it for you, this is not the goal of this site.

Comment: I do understand that but I don't actually know where to start..

Comment: Thank you for editing my list Sick, what did you do to do that for future reference?

Comment: This is a great spot to use a numbers or tally table.

Comment: Hi Sean, do you mean to compare the list of what I have stored against a list of the next, for example, 12 dates, and loop through getting the magic 5 dates?

Comment: NO there is absolutely no need for any looping for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on limited information, here's a quick hack:

```
with offsets(n) as (
    select  1 union all
    select  2 union all
    select  3 union all
    select  4 union all
    select  5 union all
    select  6 union all
    select  7 union all
    select  8 union all
    select  9 union all
    select 10 union all
    select 11
)
select top 5 dateadd(dd, n, cast(getdate() as date)) as dt from offsets
where dateadd(dd, n, cast(getdate() as date) not in (
    select dt from <exclude_dates>
)
order by dt
```

Comment: With Christmas you might get only 4 results (2 times weekend + 2 days christmas), better union with an 11.

Comment: Thank you Shawnt00..  I think this is exactly what I need..  I saw something similar for just working days (not including the weekend only) but was unsure if I could use it..  I guess I should have posted it like the guys at the top suggested anyways..  Thank you so much, I am sure this will help me.

Comment: @Alfons Yeah, I was thinking 10 was probably but that was a good scenario to catch.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to create a table of all possible dates in a year.

```
select top 5 date
from possible_dates
where date not in
   (select date from unavailable_dates)
and date > [insert startdate here]
order by date
```